# Show soft warning from clean method of Django Formset for Model Form

Tags: python, django, forms, django-forms, modelform

I've got a model form and a formset that I'm using successfully without issue.

In my `clean` method of the formset I perform some logic - but one of the requirements that previously caused a `ValidationError` is now being changed and should just be a simple warning to the user in the template.

My model form and formset look like this:

```
class AlignmentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, employee, **kwargs):
        self.person = person
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    class Meta:
        model = Alignment
        fields = [
            "alignment",
            "start_date",
            "end_date",
        ]


class AlignmentFormSet(forms.BaseModelFormSet):

    def clean(self):
        if any(self.errors):
            return

        # I've trimmed out additional logic and checks
        # This is the area of concern

        alignment_error = {}
        for i, form in enumerate(self.forms):
            if not end_date:
                if alignment == "Wrong":
                    alignment_error = {
                        "alignment": alignment,
                        "added_message": "Corrected",
                    }

        if alignment_error:
            raise forms.ValidationError(
                f"""
                The alignment is
                 ({alignment_error['alignment']}) and must
                 be ({alignment_error['added_message']}).
            """
            )

        return form
```

The current `ValidationError` needs to become just a message that is presented to the user in the template - but does not stop the form from validating and saving.

I've tried doing something like this:

```
    if alignment_error:
        messages.warning(
            request,
            f"""
            The alignment is
             ({alignment_error['alignment']}) and must
             be ({alignment_error['added_message']}).
        """,
        )
```

But that didn't work because I don't have access to request. Can I get access to it?

What is the best way to accomplish this? I still want to display the message, but just don't want it to prevent the form from saving.

EDIT TO ADD:

The views function looks like this: (the essential pieces)

```
def person(request, person_no):
    person = get_user_model().objects.get(person_no=person_no)
    formset = get_alignment_formset(person, request.POST)
    if request.method == "POST":
        # If add alignment is in form the util method will handle adding
        # the extra form if add alignment not in post data actually validate
        # and process the form
        if "add_alignment" not in request.POST:
            if formset.is_valid():
                # If form is valid we want to get the person being updated
                # current alignment
                alignment_before = Alignment.get_active_primary(person)

                for formset_form in formset:
                    if formset_form.has_changed():
                        alignment = formset_form.save(commit=False)
                        alignment.user = person
                        if not alignment.pk:
                            alignment.created_by = request.user
                        alignment.modified_by = request.user
                        alignment.save()
                    else:
                        alignment = formset_form.save(commit=False)

                # do some logic with position control here
                warnings, errors = update_foil_alignment_app(
                    request.user, person, alignment_before, alignment
                )
                if errors or warnings:
                    for error in errors:
                        messages.error(request, error)
                    for warning in warnings:
                        messages.warning(request, warning)
                    kwargs = {"person_no": person.person_no}
                    return redirect("app_name:person", **kwargs)

                messages.success(
                    request,
                    f"""
                    You have successfully updated alignments for
                     {alignment.user.last_name}, {alignment.user.first_name}.
                """,
                )
                kwargs = {"person_no": person.person_no}
                return redirect("app_name:person", **kwargs)
```

The utils function looks like this:

```
def get_alignment_formset(person, post_data=None):
    extra = 0
    # If add alignment in post_data we add the extra form and clear out
    # post data, we don't actually want to post only data
    if post_data:
        if "add_alignment" in post_data:
            post_data = None
            extra = 1
    formset = modelformset_factory(
        Alignment,
        fields=("alignment", "start_date", "end_date"),
        extra=extra,
        form=AlignmentForm,
        formset=AlignmentFormSet,
    )
    formset = formset(
        post_data or None,
        form_kwargs={"person": person},
        queryset=Alignment.exclude_denied.filter(user=person).annotate(
            num_end_date=Count("end_date")
        ).order_by(
            "-end_date",
        ),
    )
    return formset
```

Comment: can you please post your view you are using ?

Comment: @SukhpreetSingh I've added the view and the utils call that comes along with that

Answer (score 0):

I believe I've been able to pass the request in appropriately at this point by doing the following:

Views.py:

```
def person(request, person_no):
    person = get_user_model().objects.get(person_no=person_no)
    formset = get_alignment_formset(person, request.POST, request)
```

Utils.py:

```
def get_alignment_formset(person, post_data=None, request=None):
    extra = 0
    # If add alignment in post_data we add the extra form and clear out
    # post data, we don't actually want to post only data
    if post_data:
        if "add_alignment" in post_data:
            post_data = None
            extra = 1
    formset = modelformset_factory(
        Alignment,
        fields=("alignment", "start_date", "end_date"),
        extra=extra,
        form=AlignmentForm,
        formset=AlignmentFormSet,
    )
    formset = formset(
        post_data or None,
        form_kwargs={"person": person, "request": request},
        queryset=Alignment.exclude_denied.filter(user=person).annotate(
            num_end_date=Count("end_date")
        ).order_by(
            "-end_date",
        ),
    )
    return formset
```

Forms.py:

```
class AlignmentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, employee, request, **kwargs):
        self.person = person
        self.request = request
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

class AssignmentFormSet(forms.BaseModelFormSet):

    def clean(self):
        ...
        ...
        if alignment_error:
            warning = "There was an issue"
            messages.warning(form.request, warning)
```

It now shows up as a warning as expected.